# Anyone implemented google identity toolkit succefully in PHP?

Tags: php, git, api, openid, google-openid

I'm trying to implement the Google Identity Toolkit in PHP and Javascript

I've defined the 7 cases
Callback Url: Login URL: User status Signup URL: Logout URL: Home URL: Forgotten URL:

and the widget and got an api key..and I'm trying to do the same functionality as in the following example provided by google

https://account-chooser.appspot.com/

I have a problem in getting google to validate my login. I'm doing wrong my **verifyAssertion** (done with curl in php ) or the

```
window.google.identitytoolkit.notifyFederatedSuccess({ "email": "email@domain.com", "registered": true });
```

this is what happends and the problem that I have:
google has this widget that first shows you a signin with the key icon, you click on it, then you choose a google account or yahoo or whatever (this part is all ok)
you use your google account for example then a popup appears and GIT does his magic (will do a callback to your callback url) then it redirects to your site account loggedin or error depending of your callback response. 
What happens in this case it actually redirects to my site account as loggedin but the widget doesn't show that I'm actually loggedin. Not as the google's example page..
It still displays the key signing widget...

I'm doing something worng and I don't know how to fix it...

here are some more references from google. It comes a bit undocumented (createAuthUrl i didn't even used that ..don't know what is for)

http://code.google.com/apis/identitytoolkit/v1/reference.html

http://code.google.com/apis/identitytoolkit/v1/acguide.html
I've implemented  verifyAssertion with the EasyRpService in the example
What's wierd is that the response is NULL and the HTTP ERROR code is NULL as well ..no 4xx nor 200

did anyone implemented this?

Answer (score 1):

The widget doesn't automatically update.  There are two things you need to do:

1) Make sure you're updating the logged in user after authentication.  Your home page after login should have a snippet of javascript like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var userData = {
    email: 'name@idp.com', // required
    displayName: 'User Name', // optional
    photoUrl: 'http://website.com/img/user.png', // optional
  };
  window.google.identitytoolkit.updateSavedAccount(userData);
</script>
```

This makes sure the user details are in local storage on the browser which is necessary for the account chooser to display their details on next login.

Additionally, to show the logged user in the widget, you need to call showSavedAccount when initializing the widget.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  window.google.identitytoolkit.showSavedAccount("logged-in-user@domain.com");
  $("#navbar").accountChooser();
</script>
<div id="navbar"></div>
```